# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'int' BMI Calculator

Tags: python, error-handling, typeerror

```
def GetWeight():
GetWeight = 0.0   
Weight = float(input("How much do you weigh in pounds?\n "))
def GetHeight():
Heightinches = 0.0
Heightinches = input("Enter your height in inches: ")

def Calculate():
BMI = eval (GetWeight * 703 / (GetHeight * GetHeight))
print ("Your BMI is", BMI)
main()
```

The program runs until the calculate module where I get the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'int'
```

Due to your suggestions the code now looks like this:

```
def GetWeight():
GetWeight = 0.0   
Weight = float(input("How much do you weigh in pounds?\n "))

def GetHeight():
Heightinches = 0.0
Heightinches = input("Enter your height in inches:\n ")

def Calculate():
BMI = eval (GetWeight() * 703 / (GetHeight() * GetHeight()))
print("Your BMI is", BMI)
main()
```

I have revised the code, however now the program is stuck in  a continuous question/answer loop and the calculate module never starts.

```
def GetWeight():
GetWeight = 0.0   
Weight = float(input("How much do you weigh in pounds?\n "))
return GetWeight
def GetHeight():
Heightinches = 0.0
Heightinches = input("Enter your height in inches:\n ")
return GetHeight
def Calculate():
BMI = eval (GetWeight() * 703 / (GetHeight() * GetHeight()))
print("Your BMI is", BMI)
main()
```

Comment: Apart from the problem with the functions, what makes you think you need `eval`?

Comment: I thought that eval was used to get python to calculate an equation. Am I wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT**

You should be calling the functions, check out this corrected code for `Calculate`

```
def GetWeight():
  weight = float(input("How much do you weigh in pounds?\n "))
  return weight

def GetHeight():
  height = input("Enter your height in inches:\n ")
  return height

def Calculate():
  height = GetHeight()
  weight = GetWeight()
  BMI = (weight * 703) / (height * height)
  print ("Your BMI is", BMI)
```

Comment: There's no reason to be using eval here.

Comment: when adding your suggestion, the program now asks for weight, then height, and then weight again. Why is it doing this?

Comment: @RABucc, every time you call `GetWeight` or `GetHeight` it will ask the user for input. You should save the response you are getting and use it, check out the updated code here.

Comment: the error i get from this code:                                                                     `def Calculate():
    weight = GetWeight()
    height = GetHeight()
    BMI = (weight * 703) / (height * height)
    print ("Your BMI is", BMI)
main()`

Comment: is `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kirby.DESKTOP-AHMTFQK/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/BMI Calculator.py", line 27, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/kirby.DESKTOP-AHMTFQK/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/BMI Calculator.py", line 9, in main
    Calculate()
  File "C:/Users/kirby.DESKTOP-AHMTFQK/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/BMI Calculator.py", line 25, in Calculate
    BMI = (weight * 703) / (height * height)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'`

Answer (score 0):

In order to call your functions use `()` like so:

```
GetWeight() , GetHeight() ...
```

As it is right now, you are trying to multiply a *function* with an integer.

[Read more about functions in Python.](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Answer (score 0):

```
GetWeight * 703
```

Since you didn't put parentheses after the function name, it's using the value of *the function object itself* instead of the *result of calling the function*.

Put parentheses after the function name:

```
GetWeight() * 703
```

Also, your `GetWeight` and `GetHeight` functions aren't returning any values; you'll need to fix that.

Comment: At the end of each function, add a line saying `return X`, where X is the value you want to return.

Comment: so it should read as `return GetHeight`at the end of the first function?